# How do I read all of the data from a Word Table with multi-cells embedded in one row?

Tags: pandas, python-docx

In Python 3.10, I'm using the modules docx and pandas.
How do I read all of the data from  a Word Table with multi-cells embedded in one row?
[Word Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YP8F.png)

My current out from the pandas dataframe is :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr6DA.png)

Code:
[Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYOAI.png)

Comment: Please paste your code in a code block (enclosed by \`\`\`) - images make it more difficult for contributors to run your code.

Comment: ` import docx
import pandas as pd
userGuide = docx.Document('UnitStudyGuide/UG.docx')
print(len(userGuide.tables)) 
fullText = []
for para in userGuide.paragraphs:
    fullText.append(para.text)
print(fullText)
for tableData in userGuide.tables:
        data = [[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in tableData.rows]
        print(data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
        print('process table\n')
        pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", -1)
        print(df)`

Comment: Thanks Stanley for the heads up on presenting my code.